# How do I scrape AngularJS site data with conditional decision tree for each final answer?

Tags: php, json, conditional-statements, screen-scraping

Given an example URL endpoint like [this](https://www.itsworthmore.com/sell/iphone/iphone-xs-max), how would you go about scraping the final price for each combination of conditions and output it to excel in PHP?

I found the json data in the HTML and decoded it, but mixing each condition and following it through to arrive to each final total price is seeming a problem. I thought of using switch statements, but with the use of the `go_to` logic, they managed to implement copies of the same data hence risk repeating myself.

Here is how i had started out with my switch statements

```php
<?php
  $json = '';


  $json_d = json_decode($json, true);
  foreach($json_d as $s => $set){
    foreach($set['questions'] as $q => $question){
      process_question($question);

    }
  }

  function process_question($question){
    switch ($question['text']) {
      case 'What is the condition of the phone?':
        process_condition();
        break;

      default:
        # code...
        break;
    }
    // foreach($question['answers'] as $a => $answer){
    //   // print_r($answer);
    // }
  }

?>
```

Lump of json for that specific endpoint is [here](https://0bin.net/paste/BF+AKqTpQW5vXQiB#Q8V2xBtzbxdi6byAoBtQeEc7MM4RSejVuxdo4PHVUii). Wanted to keep the post short.

If you browse through the decision tree leading to each final total sum, you will know what i mean to implement and out put to excel.

Comment: Have any ideas here? I am still stuck.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, here is the JS the site uses for their decision tree. https://0bin.net/paste/F7WCfD1NhUP5DXPo#9ubqQ3LYuU6U7Rpp7JTDEWIuMeAazitYq7TyxDEIYvv

Comment: JSON logic could be easily understood by manually following the different paths in the link i provided.

Comment: Seems to be more clear now - result is a command and go_to jump to some question (probably skip some off topic, etc.). But not sure why you play with - would not be enough to keep existing IIFE, mock input or outputs and convert final result to ex. XML to be able to open by XL ? Or what is your goal or motivation when existing solution probably works even as is ?

Comment: I am mostly a system programmer, not so well versed in web technologies. Hence, don't have experience editing that JS file. Was thinking of using PHP in the end but still not my forte.

Comment: Looks like quite a big task to analyze and rewrite whole Angular script. In case only basic functionality needed, probably not so complicated, but in general bounty is not so interesting for so much work ;-)